# Delete row from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete rows from multiple tables, How do I do this?
I have tried

```
DELETE a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM table1 as a, table2 as b, table3 as c
WHERE a.colName = 'value'
AND b.colName = 'value'
AND a.c.colName = 'value';
```

`'value'` is same for all tables as well as `colName`.

For this query records must exist in all tables but in my case records may or may not exist in the tables.
When we run a delete query, it deletes the existing records, returns `'0 row(s) affected'` otherwise. So simply I want to run 3 queries like this

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE colName = 'value';
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE colName = 'value';
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE colName = 'value';
```

in one query.

Thanks

Comment: you issue one delete per table.

Comment: What would be the advantage? Your 3 line example is shorter and easier to debug. On the other hand, the single delete statement generates a huge join, for no reason. (And the reason behind yours failing is that it is an inner join, but I would _not_ recommend turning it into an outer join either.)

Comment: I am calling a PHP service to delete these records so if I send multiple queries in one query string it wont work because the PHP service calls `mysql_query($query,$link)`
mysql_query() can't execute multiple statements for security reasons...

Comment: I see. Can you try `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: @Ali look at my answer, that will delete from all tables in a single statement.

Comment: @Randy. You can delete from multiple tables in one query

Comment: Ali, I might post up a working solution but, in the meantime, also take a look at CASCADE ON DELETE

Comment: @Strawberry, Thanks for looking into it... LEFT JOIN did the trick. I have accepted the answer (see below) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete with joins is a bit strange in mysql. You need something like this:

EDIT:

To allow for rows not existing on all tables

```
DELETE FROM 
  table1, table2, table3
USING 
  table1 
LEFT JOIN 
  table2 ON table2.colName = table1.colName 
LEFT JOIN 
  table3 ON table3.colName = table1.colName 
WHERE 
  table1.colName = 'value'
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. I tried it before but it only works if the records exist in all three tables, otherwise it wont delete any record...

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit of the question. I've updated the answer to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

since your actual problem is executing mutliple queries at once. the best solution for you would be to integrate mysqli extension and use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) with these queries:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE colName = 'value';
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE colName = 'value';
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE colName = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,colname CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;

CREATE TABLE table2
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,colname CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table3;

CREATE TABLE table3
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,colname CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 (colname) VALUES ('x'),('y'),('z');

INSERT INTO table2 (colname) VALUES ('x'),('x'),('z');

INSERT INTO table3 (colname) VALUES ('y'),('y'),('z');

SELECT * FROM table1;
  +----+---------+
  | id | colname |
  +----+---------+
  |  1 | x       |
  |  2 | y       |
  |  3 | z       |
  +----+---------+

SELECT * FROM table2;
  +----+---------+
  | id | colname |
  +----+---------+
  |  1 | x       |
  |  2 | x       |
  |  3 | z       |
  +----+---------+

SELECT * FROM table3;
  +----+---------+
  | id | colname |
  +----+---------+
  |  1 | y       |
  |  2 | y       |
  |  3 | z       |
  +----+---------+

DELETE a, b, c
  FROM table1 a
  JOIN table2 b
    ON b.colname = a.colname
  JOIN table3 c
    ON c.colname = a.colname
 WHERE a.colName IN('x','z');

SELECT * FROM table1;
  +----+---------+
  | id | colname |
  +----+---------+
  |  1 | x       |
  |  2 | y       |
  +----+---------+

SELECT * FROM table2;
  +----+---------+
  | id | colname |
  +----+---------+
  |  1 | x       |
  |  2 | x       |
  +----+---------+

SELECT * FROM table3;
  +----+---------+
  | id | colname |
  +----+---------+
  |  1 | y       |
  |  2 | y       |
  +----+---------+
```

As mikea has demonstrated, you can substitute the INNER JOIN for an OUTER JOIN to remove the 'x' values altogether, despite their absence from table3

Comment: That's right... I am using LEFT JOIN and it works fine now... Thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set up a view collecting all your rows, and then delete from that view.

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT colName FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT colName FROM b
UNION ALL
SELECT colName FROM c
```

And then

```
DELETE FROM v
WHERE colName = 'value'
```